# После создания поля для редактирования курсор стал в виде "кружка"

Tags: база-данных, access

После создания поля для редактирования на "000_000_Form1" курсор стал в виде "кружка".
Как будто, что-то грузится.

**Вопрос.**
Как устранить проблему?

[**ССЫЛКА**](http://transfiles.ru/ftng9) на файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С какой алгоритмической проблемой вы столкнулись? Опишите поподробнее. Или ваша проблема связана с системным администрированием?

Comment: @vp_arth Захожу в форму  "000_000_Form1" курсор мыши сразу из стрелки(как по умолчанию) превращается в кружок, как при загрузке чего-нибудь.. Что происходит не понимаю

Comment: Смотрите макросы, скорее всего у вас выполняется какой-то код.